# Validation of an ID

Tags: loops, validation, delphi

Im creating a code that will validate if the user enter all digits as the user is entering an ID. I have a code but I cant figure out how to complete it.

```
var name:string;
    i,c:integer; 
    ch:char; 
begin
 name:Edit1.text;
 n:length(name);
  for i := 0 to n do 
    begin 
     ch:=name[i];
     //not code// 
     if ch= any digits then showmessage invalid else showmessage valid;
```

Comment: Depends on the Delphi version and precisely what you mean by digits and letters. There isn't a single universally accepted definition of what is meant by digits and letters. Do you know what you mean? And are you 100% sure that it's wise? More often than not such validation just stops people from doing perfectly reasonable tasks. What are you hoping to achieve by placing limits on what your users can do?

Comment: What criterias of adding text? Should it be *only* digits or *only* letters? Or mixing of them is allowed?

Comment: A code that determins if the value that determines if the value only has digits. If any letter is added then it will say the value is invalid

Comment: @David heffernan I'm using this code to validate if the user enters a correct ID and a correct name. The ID cant have letters and a name cant have digits

Comment: I would use `TryStrToInt/64()` for the ID validation, no need to check the digits manually.

Comment: Still not clear. Still not sure what is meant by a digit. Do you mean the 10 ASCII characters 0 to 9, or do you admit broader Unicode digits? At least your edit makes it clear that you are concerned just with looking for digits, which is at least clearer. It's still a little imprecise though.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet does not match your question description. You ask about ID validation, but then show code for name validation instead.

In any case, try something like the following:

```
function IsDigit(c: Char): boolean; inline;
begin
  Result := (c >= '0') and (c <= '9');
  {
  Or Result := CharInSet(c, ['0'..'9']);
  Or Result := Character.IsDigit(c);
  Or Result := c.IsDigit();
  } 
end;
```

Name check:

```
var
  name: String;
  i: Integer;
  ch: Char;
begin
  name := Edit1.Text;
  n := Length(name);
  for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    ch := name[i];
    if IsDigit(ch) then
    begin
      ShowMessage('invalid');
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  ShowMessage('valid');
end;
```

ID check:

```
var
  id: String;
  i: Integer;
  ch: Char;
begin
  id := Edit2.Text;
  n := Length(id);
  if n = 0 then
  begin
    ShowMessage('invalid');
    Exit;
  end;
  for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    ch := id[i];
    if not IsDigit(ch) then
    begin
      ShowMessage('invalid');
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  ShowMessage('valid');
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
var
  id: Integer; // or Int64
begin
  if not TryStrToInt(Edit2.Text, id) then // or TryStrToInt64()
    ShowMessage('invalid')
  else
    ShowMessage('valid');
end;
```

Comment: Rather than use a set, I'd just check that the character is between '0' and '9', since these characters have consecutive ordinals

Comment: Thanks for the ans

Comment: I tried this and you can also use a const to make it easier

Comment: @DavidHeffernan well, for that matter, one could alternately use [`Character.IsDigit()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Character.IsDigit) or [`TCharHelper.IsDigit()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Character.TCharHelper.IsDigit). There are many ways to solve this

Comment: IsDigit has different behaviour though because there are more digits than just the 10 ASCII ones. So user has got to decide what they want.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan perhaps, but if the user's input is in ASCII then that issue is moot.